ASP.Net Core Force to Use Brotli
It doesn't matter what I do in AddResponseCompression(), Web Service always Compress with Gzip. I want to Use brotli. I've tested :
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression();

///////////

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
});

///////////

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.MimeTypes = new[] {
        "text/html",
        "text/css",
        ..
        .
    };
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
});

///////////

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});

As you can see in the image below, always Gzip. But I found that the html page it self get br Content-Encoding.

It is worth mentioning that both static and dynamic content compression is enabled in IIS and all mime types are selected.
UPDATE: It suddenly Fixed! WOW. but how? nothing has changed. exactly NOTHING!
I tested again on another project. AddResponseCompression() then UseResponseCompression() after UseStaticFiles() and again the same happened. Gzip on all!
maybe I should submit an issue for Dotnet?

Just to make sure - did you enable the middleware with UseResponseCompression call?

Also, enabling compression for HTTPS protocol introduces some security breaches which have to be mitigated with CSRF tokens.

Yes I enabled UseResponseCompression After UseStaticFiles And I am aware of security breaches. Thank you

You can set the compression method in applicationHost.config like this:
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="br" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iisbrotli.dll" />
</httpCompression>

More information you can refer to this link:
Higher Compression Ratio with Brotli compression.
Brotli IIS Compression Scheme Plugin.

Thanks for your answer but my question is why it is happening? I don't know how but it fixed suddenly! I even posted an issue for dotnet team, but they didn't respond yet. I'll update my question if they answer or fix it. thanks again
